# Cleos - Unable to connect with Keosd via Unix Socket Path

Tags: cleos, keosd

```
cleos --wallet-url unix://home/user/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock 
wallet list
```

1. Unable to connect with keosd

Error :-

```
 unix://home/user/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock; is keosd running?
```

While Keosd is successfully running with no error at

```
keosd --unix-socket-path keosd
```

Keosd running log

```
keosd --unix-socket-path //home/user/ksd/keosd.sock

info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.345 thread-0  wallet_plugin.cpp:42          plugin_initialize    ] initializing wallet plugin
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.345 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/keosd/stop
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  wallet_api_plugin.cpp:73      plugin_startup       ] starting wallet_api_plugin
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create_key
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/get_public_keys
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/import_key
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_keys
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_wallets
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock_all
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/open
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/remove_key
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/set_timeout
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_digest
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.346 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction
info  2018-12-03T11:06:50.347 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/unlock
```

I tried to change the unix socket path but still same error

When i further test on keosd using http server address and result are unexcepted

2. Keosd - Unable to configure host to listen on any port

`keosd --http-server-address http://127.0.0.1:8899`

Error

```
error 2018-12-03T12:56:13.410 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:425           plugin_initialize    ] failed to configure http to listen on http://127.0.0.1:8899 (resolve: Service not found)
```

EOSIO v1.5.0-rc2 and tried on v1.4.4

Answer (score 2):

If i don't run keosd and run that command

```
cleos --print-request --print-response wallet list
```

That is the result i get from console that clearly tell me it's not using ip/port but unix socket as a host

```
Wallets:
REQUEST:
---------------------
POST /v1/wallet/list_wallets HTTP/1.0
Host: /home/user/eosio-wallet/keosd.sock:
content-length: 0
Accept: */*
Connection: close


---------------------
RESPONSE:
---------------------
[]
---------------------
[]
```

It doesn't work with absolute Path yet so i tried with relative Path to keosd data-dir and it worked

```
cleos --wallet-url unix://keosd.sock wallet list

Wallets:
[
  "default"
]
```

For the Second Question, someone told me to not write http, i.e

```
keosd --http-server-address 127.0.0.1:8899
```

I don't know why they remove it and what is the reason behind that?